# Remove slash automatically on a page builder WP

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a website here: http://goo.gl/WauFiy

And my issue is there is part on the pricing plan w/c uses a page builder and by default adds a slash "/"

[image]

There is however no option on the page builder to remove this. I am trying to look for some ways to hide this or just remove it if you are going to inspect element on this part you'll see these codes:

```
<div class="plan-icon">

<h5>"/"<span>Video Production</span>
<h5>
<strong>Promotional Video</strong>

</div>
```

Is there any out there who has an idea to remove this slash?

Comment: This could be done both by Javascript and PHP using the `preg_replace`  or `string.replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your website uses jQuery, therefore, edit your main theme file, any of (index.php, header.php, footer.php) and put the following code:

```
$('h5').contents().first().replaceWith("");
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tc4jfabd/2/

**Update:** 
You can easily remove the slash by editing your theme .php files. Go to **Appearance > Editor** and search for `class="plan-icon"` in the files, when found, then remove the slash which is located under `<h5>` tag.

Comment: @RodelGarcia Down vote? it depends how you implement it. I created fiddle example for you and it works.

Comment: how i can place it specifically?

Comment: Can you provide your website link? This could be placed through many methods. The easiest way is to open theme's Javascript file and pasted it there.

Comment: Go to > Appearance >  Editor and there, find the main theme file. It should be `main.php` or `index.php` or look for files and fine the file that has `head` tag and put it there as script. You can also remove the backslash by searching these files are finding it the piece of code there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100433/discussion-between-maihan-nijat-and-rodel-garcia).

Answer (score 0):

You also can do it with the help of css like in this way:

in your style.css , try to modify like this:

```
.pricing h5 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #414141;
    /* added text indent */
    text-indent: 9999px;
}
```

May be this can help you.